# Waiting for animation to be completed and then continue in loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a problem. I'm trying to programme a snow jQuery plugin for my websites but now I need to wait till one animation of one element is completed before next will appear. Hope you know what I think. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height();

var startw = 0;

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    startw = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
    $('<div class="flake" id="' + i + '"></div>').appendTo('body');
    var element = ".flake#" + i;
    $(element).css('margin-left', startw + 'px');
    $(element).animate({'margin-top': height-18}, 1000).delay(350).fadeOut(250);
}
```

});

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/JacobArbet/5yfCR/)

Comment: You can put the other animations in the callbacks of the original animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the 'lifespan' of each flake is going to be 1600ms, so you could just use `setTimeout` with a timeout of `i*1600`:

```
$(function () {
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();
    var flakeLifeSpan = 1600;

    var startw = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            startw = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * width);
            var element = $('<div class="flake"">F</div>');
            element.appendTo($("body"));
            $(element).css('margin-left', startw + 'px');
            $(element).animate({
                'margin-top': height - 18
            }, 1000).delay(350).fadeOut(250);
        }, i * flakeLifeSpan);
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CLyt7/10/)**

I used `F` to see the flake, I assume you'll have a image set by CSS. Just remove the `F` for your purposes.